# Can I travel with Zopiclone to the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, health, drugs

I have been prescribed Zopiclone 3.75mg by my Scottish GP for occasional insomnia. I will be traveling to the US in about a month, and I'm planning on bringing a limited supply (7 tablets) in case I need it there. They will be in the original packet with my name on it, and I'll also have a copy of my NHS prescription.

Zopiclone is a Schedule IV drug according to the DEA. The FDA has not authorized the Zopiclone for sale in the US, though a related drug, Eszopiclone (aka Lunesta), is available in the US (also Schedule IV; not available in Europe).

Will the original packet and copy of the prescription be enough? Or am I simply not allowed to bring Zopiclone with me to the US?

Comment: Thanks. In part it does... My medication isn't an opioid. However, it is in the controlled substances list. And I'll be complying with 21 CFR 1301.26. I was wondering rather if the difference in regulation has any bearing on my being able to travel with it?

Comment: Because Zopiclone is a prescription medication, seems to me its import is covered by the CBP advice. (The advice is addressed to importing prescription medications, not just opioids as asked in that question.) What do you mean by "difference in regulation?"

Comment: I mean that it is not available in the US, whereas it is available in Europe. Or am I overthinking this? It would be useful to know what the friend of that OP ended up doing...

Comment: My opinion is you're overthinking it. Nothing in the CBP guidance requires that the prescribed drug be available in the US.

Comment: Thanks! I'll just bring the prescription then. Edit: In fact, looking closely at the DEA list, Zopiclone has "Lunesta" as its "Other name," though that's technically not wholly correct.